# subset a dataset when the variables in the dataset matches a variable list

Tags: sas, subset

I'm dealing with one data problem in sas.
I have one dateset including 1000 variables and 1000 records for each variable.
And I have another variable list which includes 100 variable names.
I'd like to subset the first dataset when the variable names in that dataset match the variable list.

I tried `proc merge` and `proc sql`, but cannot work it out.
Could any one help me out?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You should describe the structure of your tables if you want someone to write the code that works as intended. Sample data would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

SAS keeps or drops variables with the conveniently named keywords 'keep' and 'drop'.  PROC SQL can help you generate a list if you don't already have it in text format.

```
data want;
set have;
keep var1 var2 var3 var4;
run;
```

If you have the list of variables in dataset "vnames" with the variable "tokeep", you can do this:

```
proc sql;
select tokeep into :keeplist separated by ' ' from vnames;
quit;

data want;
set have;
keep &keeplist.;
run;
```

PROC SQL is taking the contents of 'tokeep' and instead of selecting them to a table or the screen, putting them in a space-delimited list inside a macro variable 'keeplist', which then is used as the arguments for the 'keep' statement.

Comment: I tried your code as proc sql;
select tokeep into :keeplist separated by ' ' from list;
quit; but it doesn't work. i don't know why

Comment: Since you didn't explain how it didn't work, I don't know why either :)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375139/how-to-read-variable-names-in-a-sas-data-set) you can find how to output a list of all the variable names of a dataset as another dataset. This will make it way easier to decide which of the big datasets you will use and which you will not (e.g. a left (or right) join of variable names, then look at the number of rows is at least the count of variables which you want to have).